# Get parent of current page

Tags: pages, page-template, list, wp-list-pages

please help me: I need to get the parent of the current page, in other words: to get the parent of $direct_parent.Thanks!

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $direct_parent = $post->post_parent;
    $parent = $direct_parent->post_parent;
wp_list_pages( array(
    'child_of' => $parent,
    'title_li'     => false,
    'depth' => 1
) );
?>
```

This code doesn't work(

Answer (score 3):

Try using **get_post_ancestors**. Here is how you can apply this in your case:

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $post = $wp_query->post;
    $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post);
    if( empty($post->post_parent) ) {
        $parent = $post->ID;
    } else {
        $parent = end($ancestors);
    } 
    if(wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=0" )) {                
        wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&depth=1" ); 
    } 
?>
```

You'll probably need to remove the depth parameters to show you're 3rd level pages.

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$parent` in `child_of` argument of `wp_list_pages` by `parent->ID`.
`wp_list_pages` needs the post id instead of post object.

```
<?php 
  global $post;
  $direct_parent = $post->post_parent;
  $parent = $direct_parent->post_parent;
  wp_list_pages( array(
   'child_of' => $parent,
   'title_li'     => false,
   'depth' => 1
 ) );
?>
```